# QUERY() to get rows below a certain cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm downloading a CSV file from an external API. It returns a table with the following structure:

```
foo
bar    1    4
baz    2    3
```

Is there any way to make a [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) (or some other function?) to get the first two rows below the `foo` cell?

There are several other occurrences of `bar` and `baz` rows, that's why I only want the ones below the `foo` cell. Doable?

Comment: Is there only one foo in the dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one alternative also: using regexextract and concatenate , with the additional rept function to grab each of the values , pretending the url is in A1:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"(Basic)"&rept("(\d\.\d{1,3})",6))

=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"(Diluted)"&rept("(\d\.\d{1,3})",6))
```

comes out looking like this:

[image]

if you want to be doubly sure: add the Earnings per share in front of basic:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"Earnings per share(Basic)"&rept("(\d\.\d{1,3})",6))

=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"Earnings per shareBasic.*(Diluted)"&rept("(\d\.\d{1,3})",6))
```

To have the output all on one line, one after the other:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"Earnings per share(Basic)"&rept("(\d\.\d{1,3})",6)&"(Diluted)"&rept("(\d\.\d{1,3})",6))
```

[image]

Basically if you want to see the raw data , remove the regex part and just leave the concatenate and the importdata - the regex part helps to ignore the beginning portion and then specify which pieces to capture using the parentheses. These are called capture groups. Anything outside of them technically gets ignored.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still guaranteed to get the "Earnings per share" though, right? This just matches the first occurrence of Basic or Diluted?

Comment: yes - but if you want to be extra sure: wrap it in this: regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(T716)),"Earnings per share(Basic)"&rept("(\d\.\d{2})",6))

Comment: I see, seems to work fine for "Basic". "Diluted" on the other hand throws an error. What do I need to change besides the text?

Comment: do you want them all on one line or on two lines? i also edited above to include diluted

Comment: Might as well take get both at once if possible :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Hmm are you getting your Diluted example to work? :) `=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"Earnings per shareBasic.*(Diluted)"&rept("(\d\.\d{2})",6))` throws an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104242/discussion-between-aurielle-perlmann-and-filur).

Answer (score 1):

try this formula:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(A1:C13,row(A1:C13)>MATCH("foo",A1:A13,0)),"select * limit 2")
```

[example workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16DkD0_LmCOiRVOQWQoDrPBL447P4_CKStM_PTgcgcv8/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: Sample]

To use imported data instead of range, use:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(Data,row(Data)>MATCH("foo",query(Data,"select Col1"),0)),"select * limit 2")
```

Comment: Thank you, look good! How would I reference a sheet which I fetch using IMPORTDATA()? I would like to avoid importing it to my actual sheet before making queries on it, if possible?

Comment: I think, '=QUERY(FILTER(Data,row(Data)>MATCH("foo",query(Data,"select Col1"),0)),"select * limit 2")' will do it

Comment: Here is an example of the actual data: `=IMPORTDATA("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=SHB a&region=SE&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&number=3")`. What I want is the two rows below "Earnings per share".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=query(A2:C,"select * where A='bar' or A='baz' limit 2")
```

Comment: It needs to be based on ´foo´ somehow since there are multiple ocurrences of bar and baz as I mentioned...